# How to shuffle parts of a function represented as a sum in R?

Tags: r

If I have any numerical function in R such as :

```
objFun=function(x) return(x^2+x+1)
```

How can I shuffle parts of any function in R using a uniform law ?

**Example :**

The Parts of "objFun" are x^2 & x & 1.

First I need to retrieve the number of components which is n=3, then I should store x^2 & x & 1 in a table with dimension=3.

After that, I can store those parts in a variable tmp such as  :

```
if (uniform law return 1 ) then : tmp= x^2
if (uniform law return 2 ) then : tmp= x
if (uniform law return 3)  then : tmp= 1
```

I didn't give my try because I don't know how to divide a numerical function in R.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do more clearly? An example of how this function would work and what results you'd expect to get would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how "generic" your "uniform law" is. It appears that you want to separate elements in a polynomial expression. Assuming that, and assuming that everything else in a simple function is irrelevant, this would work as a starting point:

```
objFun=function(x) return(x^2+x+1) 
objFun

functionElements <- function(fn) {
  # Regular expression of the function body
  # Remove anything ahead of an open parenthesis (
  # Remove anything after a close parenthesis )
  # split on the 4 main arithmetic functions, +, -, * and /
  # double backslash means "match the next character exactly", since +, *, -, / have regular expression meanings
  # | means "or"
  splitElements <- strsplit(split = ".*\\(|\\+|\\*| |\\).*|\\/|\\-", deparse(body(fn)))[[1]]
  # remove empty parts ('non zero character')
  splitElements <- splitElements[nzchar(splitElements)]
  splitElements
}

functionElements(objFun)
```

It is not clear how you wanted the `tmp` variable to be, but from the above you could modify to get what you want.